# is there a hosted web app I can use to test WS-I BP1 soap compliance?

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl

I have a url that has a wsdl from a vendor and would like to run a hosted tool and just forward him the results.

Does such a webtool exist where I can just type in the url of the wsdl?  (or do really have to download soapui or other stuff to do something like this...yuck).

Looking for a quick way to test it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way if you have .NET is to run the WSDL and any associated XML schemas through the svcutil.exe program. It complains about many compliance violations. The older WSDL.EXE tool also will complain for many of them.

There are also tools to do this. I have used the SoapScope tool from Mindreef. They have been purchased by Progress Software, and it appears the tool may now be [**Actional** Application Development](http://www.progress.com/en/actional/actional-application-development.html).